# inkscape keyboard shortcut for resize

Tags: inkscape, resize, shortcuts

What is the inkscape keyboard shortcut (no mouse drag) equivalent of 
`Ctrl+mouse drag` to resize an object? 
I am trying to resize 2 objects by same factor. However with mouse it is difficult to know how much is resize. Selecting both object together and resizing using `Ctrl+mouse drag` moves 2nd object out of original position!

Comment: When resizing two or more objects, you are resizing the space separating them as well. When I need to resize in a precise manner, I change the units to percent on the toolbar and enter a value. Is this an option for your objective?

Answer (score 1):

If you group the two objects together, they will both resize by the same factor and remain in their original positions in relation to one another.

Alternatively, you could click the lock icon on your sizing toolbar and use the up or down arrow to adjust the size a little bit at a time, but I think just grouping them together should do the trick.

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the transform dialog (Object > Transform), and activate the checkbox 'Apply to each object separately' for having full numerical control.

The complete keyboard shortcut list (for other shortcuts) is available online:
https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys092.html

There is no shortcut for resizing without the mouse other than via the transform dialog or the input fields in the selection tool's tool controls.